# swift:How to save the base64String encoded Image into local directory

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to save my photo into local directory. I have used `UIImagePickerView` Controller using `Swift`. After uploading the picture i got the response of picture uploaded in **base64String**.

I convert them as follows:

```
//encoding
let base64String = imageData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
print(base64String)


//decoding
let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: base64String, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
var decodedimage = UIImage(data: decodedData!)
print(decodedimage)

//Turning base64 encoded string into an NSData
let encodedImageData = base64String
let FinalimageData = NSData(base64EncodedString: encodedImageData, options: [])
print(FinalimageData)

let image = UIImage(data: FinalimageData!)
```

**Requirement:**

> I want to save the image to my local directory. How can i do this using `Swift 2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save image in local directory in following way. Add Image extension with `fileName`.

```
let filePath = "\(NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0])/\(fileName)"
let imageData : Data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)! as Data
 imageData.write(toFile: filePath, atomically: true)
```

Comment: my NSDATA is let imageData : NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(pickedImage)!

Answer (score 0):

```
let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    let fileURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("\(fileName).png")
    if let pngImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) {
    pngImageData.write(to: fileURL, options: .atomic)
}
```